# how to check if one list has triple the values of another list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I just had this Prolog question on an exam, I'm pretty sure I didn't get it right.

I had to define triple(List1,List2), example triple([1,2,3],[3,6,9]) and triple([2,4],[6,12]) are true.

My attempt was this, but I suspect it doesn't work ...

```
triple([],[]).
triple([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
    triple(T1,T2),
    H1 = H2 * 3.
```

Anyone know the correct solution?  (Note, this is not homework, just curious about an exam question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to check whether an expression evaluates to the same value (and type) as another expression, use `is/2`, rather than unification `=/2`.

So instead of

```
H1 = H2 * 3
```

It should be:

```
H2 is H1 * 3
```

<sub>You also seem to be slightly confused on which side to multiply by 3.</sub>

Note that [`is/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2) is declared as `-Number is +Expr`, so the expression `H1 * 3` must be on the right hand side.

Note that `is/2` will also check the specific type of the [`number`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=number/1), which can be either `integer` or `float`. Therefore, the unification will fail when one side is `float` and the other side is `integer` even if the value is equal.

```
quad([],[]).
quad([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
    triple(T1,T2),
    H2 is H1 * 4.
```

`quad([0.25], [1])` will return `false`.

If you want to compare the **value** of the `number`, regardless whether it is `integer` or `float`, use [`=:=/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D%3a%3D%29/2) operator.

```
H2 =:= H1 * 3
```

or

```
H1 * 3 =:= H2
```

Since `=:=/2` is declared as `+Expr1 =:= +Expr2`, it offers more freedom in both sides of the operator (both sides can be expression, as opposed to only 1 side in `is/2`). However, it also requires that both sides are instantiated when it is evaluated.

Simply put, the `is` version will allow you to evaluate `A` in `triple([1,2,3],A).`. On the other hand, the `=:=` version will return `true` for `triple([1],[3.0]).` (value comparison), but restrict you to checking only.

Comment: Actually, it should probably be `H2 =:= H1 * 3` if we want to be pedantic about it.

Comment: @Boris: Answer expanded. Please tell me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Thx!  Looks like I was on the right track -- hopefully in the exam I wrote `Hb = Ha * 3` and the only bit I did wrong was `=` instead of `is`, and I'll only lose a couple marks for the slip up.

Comment: @RobertHume: The other answer is the more "practical" one - may not be what your professor expects in an exam, but I think it is more flexible than `is/2` and `=:=/2`

Answer (score 0):

*If* we can restrict to integer lists, we can use library([clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.7%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpfd.html%27%29%29)):

```
?- [library(clpfd)].
?- [user].
|: triple(X, Y) :- maplist(tri, X, Y).
|: tri(X, Y) :- X * 3 #= Y.
|: % user://1 compiled 0,13 sec, 5 clauses
true.

?- triple([2,X,Y],[Z,9,12]).
X = 3,
Y = 4,
Z = 6.
```

To handle floating point expressions, there is library([clpr](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.8%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpqr.html%27%29%29)):

```
?- [library(clpr)].
?- [user].
|: triplef(X, Y) :- maplist(mult(3), X, Y).
|: mult(F,X,Y) :- {X * F = Y}.
|: % user://3 compiled 0,27 sec, 79 clauses
true.

?- triplef([2,X,Y],[Z,9,12]).
X = 3.0,
Y = 4.0,
Z = 6.0 .
```

I've coded triplef/3 a bit better than triple/3, by means of a *reusable* mult/3.